# How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe

I have created one GUI in which I have used a JFrame. How should I make it Modal?

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a JDialog instead of a JFrame if you want to make the window modal.  Check out [details on the introduction of the Modality API in Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140695.html) for info.  There is also [a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Here is some sample code which will display a `JPanel panel` in a `JDialog` which is modal to `Frame parentFrame`.  Except for the constructor, this follows the same pattern as opening a `JFrame`.

```
final JDialog frame = new JDialog(parentFrame, frameTitle, true);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Edit: updated Modality API link & added tutorial link (nod to @spork for the bump).

Comment: Afraid that appears to be the only solution.  I'm fighting this same problem with some inherited code.  I've got a JFrame that I really need to be modal.  Doing the work to convert it all to JDialog is really going to be ugly...  :-(

Comment: Can you hack it through? Create an invisible, modal JDialog, make it instantiate the JFrame, and, when the JFrame is closed, capture the values if necessary, and close the JDialog

Comment: The link is broken :( still people trying to learn from this 3 years on! Try this in 2013: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Comment: updated link to original article & added sporks tutorial link - thanks.

Comment: I didn't find changing over to JDialog ugly at all.  This was an easy change.

Answer (score 20):

You can create a class that is passed a reference to the parent `JFrame` and holds it in a `JFrame` variable. Then you can lock the frame that created your new frame.

```
parentFrame.disable();

//Some actions

parentFrame.enable();
```

Comment: nice, made me think on a loop to "suspend" (sleep) the application while the frame isVisible(), thx!

Comment: Kamil, Imgonzalves, can you clarify for me? Are you saying the new class should be  created in the JDialog, JFrame or whatever that creates the OP's subject JFrame?

Answer (score 12):

just replace `JFrame` to `JDialog` in class

```
public class MyDialog extends JFrame // delete JFrame and write JDialog
```

and then write `setModal(true);` in constructor

After that you will be able to construct your Form in netbeans
and the form becomes modal

Comment: Was not aware of `setModal(true);`.. this is great

Comment: need to tell that this not working under netbeans because his form editor sets the close operation on closing dialogue wich is not allowed in jdialog

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a new JPanel form
2. Add your desired components and code to it

---

```
YourJPanelForm stuff = new YourJPanelForm();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,stuff,"Your title here bro",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Your modal dialog awaits...

Comment: Ou, but there is an OK button, which I don't want.

Comment: Wait what? You can just add the JPanel to the JDialog like that?

Comment: this has nothing to do with a jFrame

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, JFrame cannot do Modal mode. Use JDialog instead and call [`setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType type)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType-java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType-) to set it to be modal (or not modal).

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to use a JDialog instead of a JFrame, you can set the **ModalityType** to **APPLICATION_MODAL**.

This provides identical behaviour to your typical JOptionPane:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MyDialog extends JFrame {

public MyDialog() {
    setBounds(300, 300, 300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton btn = new JButton("TEST");
    add(btn);
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            showDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void showDialog() 
{

    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    //OR, you can do the following...
    //JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    //dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    dialog.setBounds(350, 350, 200, 200);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    new MyDialog();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This static utility method shows a modal JFrame by secretly opening a modal JDialog, too. I used this successfully and with proper behavior on Windows 7, 8, and 10-with-multiple-desktops.

It's a nice example for the very rarely used feature of *local* classes.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

// ... (class declaration)

/**
 * Shows an already existing JFrame as if it were a modal JDialog. JFrames have the upside that they can be
 * maximized.
 * <p>
 * A hidden modal JDialog is "shown" to effect the modality.
 * <p>
 * When the JFrame is closed, this method's listener will pick up on that, close the modal JDialog, and remove the
 * listener.
 *
 * made by dreamspace-president.com
 *
 * @param window the JFrame to be shown
 * @param owner  the owner window (can be null)
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if argument "window" is null
 */
public static void showModalJFrame(final JFrame window, final Frame owner) {

    if (window == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    window.setModalExclusionType(Dialog.ModalExclusionType.APPLICATION_EXCLUDE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

    final JDialog hiddenDialogForModality = new JDialog(owner, true);
    final class MyWindowCloseListener extends WindowAdapter {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(final WindowEvent e) {
            window.dispose();
            hiddenDialogForModality.dispose();
        }
    }

    final MyWindowCloseListener myWindowCloseListener = new MyWindowCloseListener();
    window.addWindowListener(myWindowCloseListener);

    final Dimension smallSize = new Dimension(80, 80);
    hiddenDialogForModality.setMinimumSize(smallSize);
    hiddenDialogForModality.setSize(smallSize);
    hiddenDialogForModality.setMaximumSize(smallSize);
    hiddenDialogForModality.setLocation(-smallSize.width * 2, -smallSize.height * 2);
    hiddenDialogForModality.setVisible(true);
    window.removeWindowListener(myWindowCloseListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only code that have worked for me:

```
childFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

This code should be called on the main/parent frame before making the child/modal frame visible. Your child/modal frame should also have this code:

```
parentFrame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
this.mainFrame.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

"Simply" way to show any framea in dialog mode

```
public static void showFrameAsDialog(Component parentComponent, JFrame frame)
{
    try
    {
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(frame.getContentPane(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, null,
                new Object[]
                {
                }, null);

        pane.setComponentOrientation(((parentComponent == null)
                ? getRootFrame() : parentComponent).getComponentOrientation());

        int style = JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG;

        Method method = pane.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("createDialog", Component.class, String.class, int.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object objDialog = method.invoke(pane, parentComponent, frame.getTitle(), style);

        JDialog dialog = (JDialog) objDialog;
        if (frame.getWidth() > dialog.getWidth() || frame.getHeight() > dialog.getHeight())
        {
            dialog.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parentComponent);
        }

        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent)
            {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        dialog.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: WTF?! but it work

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in this case is, in the primary jframe that I want to keep visible (for example, a menu frame), I deselect the option `focusableWindowState` in the property window so It will be `FALSE`. Once that is done, the jframes I call don´t lose focus until I close them.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you could use JDialog. If you don't have access to the parent frame or you want to freeze the hole application just pass null as a parent:

`final JDialog frame = new JDialog((JFrame)null, frameTitle, true);`
`frame.setModal(true);`
`frame.getContentPane().add(panel);`
`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`
`frame.pack();`
`frame.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score -1):

There's a bit of code that might help:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class ModalJFrame extends JFrame {

    Object currentWindow = this;

    public ModalJFrame() 
    {
        super();
        super.setTitle("Main JFrame");
        super.setSize(500, 500);
        super.setResizable(true);
        super.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        super.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        JMenuItem newAction = new JMenuItem("New");
        JMenuItem openAction = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem exitAction = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        JMenuItem cutAction = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        JMenuItem copyAction = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        JMenuItem pasteAction= new JMenuItem("Paste");

        fileMenu.add(newAction);
        fileMenu.add(openAction);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(exitAction);

        editMenu.add(cutAction);
        editMenu.add(copyAction);
        editMenu.addSeparator();
        editMenu.add(pasteAction);

        newAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {

                JFrame popupJFrame = new JFrame();

                popupJFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                {
                      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                      {
                          ((Component) currentWindow).setEnabled(true);                     }
                      });

                ((Component) currentWindow).setEnabled(false);
                popupJFrame.setTitle("Pop up JFrame");
                popupJFrame.setSize(400, 500);
                popupJFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                popupJFrame.setResizable(false);
                popupJFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(getRootPane());
                popupJFrame.setVisible(true);
                popupJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });

        exitAction.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ModalJFrame myWindow = new ModalJFrame();
        myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

not sure the contetns of your JFrame, if you ask some input from users, you can use JOptionPane, this also can set JFrame as modal

```
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            String bigList[] = new String[30];

            for (int i = 0; i < bigList.length; i++) {
              bigList[i] = Integer.toString(i);
            }

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    frame, 
                    "Select a item", 
                    "The List", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    bigList,
                    "none");
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

The most simple way is to use *pack()* method before visualizing the *JFrame* object. here is an example:

```
myFrame frm = new myFrame();
frm.pack();
frm.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: how is this even related?