# How to make a modal JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

I have 2 JFrames one is the main JFrame and the other one is a sub JFrame, and I'm trying to make the main JFrame inaccessible to user interactions when I display the sub JFrame.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to make a modal JFrame?

Don't. Use a modal JDialog -- that's precisely what they're for. You understand of course that a JDialog can hold a complex GUI, as complex as any held by a JFrame.

We often run into posts like these by folks who use a GUI-builder such as NetBeans to help them create their GUI's, and since the second window's code was created by the builder to extend a JFrame, it's very hard for the programmer to go back and change it to a dialog.  The way to fix this is to try to gear your Swing code creation towards creation of JPanels, not top-level windows such as JFrames. This way you could use the created JPanel in a JFrame if desired, a JDialog if desired, a JApplet, or even another JPanel, whatever works best for the situation. This will increase your code's flexibility tremendously.

Comment: I am using jframe only. Can you give the code?

Comment: There is no "code" to give as it all depends on how you're trying to do things here. First and foremost -- read the Swing tutorials to see how to code with Swing. Next, show us your code. I would be more than happy to help you work with your code.

Comment: EmployeeForm sub=new EmployeeForm();   
       sub.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      sub.setVisible(true);   
   this.setEnabled(false);

Comment: this code help me to make sub frame as modal. But now my problem is how will i set the mainJFrame as the active form after closing the subJFrame?

Comment: Again -- don't use a JFrame -- use a JDialog. What about this advice confuses you?

Comment: My little contribute:
frame.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
          frame.requestFocus();
   }
});

Answer (score 4):

use `JDialog` and send the third parameter to its constructor as `true` (modal)

Comment: How to add a 'cancel' button in jdialog?

Comment: any JButton and in its click event write "this.dispose();"