# Holding code idle while (new)GUI waits for input

Tags: java, user-interface, user-input, wait

I am trying to get a user email to verify that it is the user. Before this I run a series of test to see if the user does need to input the email. I am struggling to create create the frame **once** and wait for the user to input their email into the required field.

What happens is the window is not generated and eats up all available processing power. I have tried `wait() / notify()` and timers but neither are doing what I need.

Is there a better way to (within a `if / else` block) to generate a window and wait for a user input before doing anything else?

```
public class Security extends JFrame{

   //Code stuff here to see if this is needed

   String email = "";
   boolean windowCreation = true;

   do{
       do{
           EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   try {
                       Security frame = new Security();
                       frame.setVisible(true); 
                       windowCreation = false;
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });
       }while(windowCreation);
   } while(!email.equals(""));

   //More code stuff here to use "email" the way I need to 
}
```

Here is the just of what the window is doing

```
 Security()
 {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
            if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                Security.email = field.getText();
            }
        }
    });
    textField.setBounds(10, 115, 415, 20);
    getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

}
```

Comment: This is what a modal JDialog is for. Use this instead of a JFrame when you want to show a sub-window that pauses the program until the dialog window is no longer visible. Get rid of the while loops -- while this is appropriate for linear console code, this sort of construct does not belong in an event-driven program. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351505/how-to-make-a-modal-jframe/8351509#8351509). Also look at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017063/passing-values-between-jframes/7017147#7017147)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels are you able to explain why my original code does not work? (also thank you for showing me JDialogs solved the problem quite nicely :3 )

Comment: I didn't bother running your code, but all I can say is it is code that should never be used. Again that type of while loop have no place within an event-driven world. It's a hack, and a dangerous one at that.