# Dispose JDialog by code, don't let the user close it

Tags: java, swing, dispose, jdialog

I have a short code, i would like to dispose a dialog, but don't want the user to be able to close it, it just doesnt work, help me please.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class Processing extends JOptionPane{

    JDialog jd;
    public Processing(){
        super(null, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{});
        Icon processPic = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Judit\\Desktop\\Mesekocka3D"
                + "\\externals\\pics\\szamitas.gif");

        setMessage(processPic);
        jd = createDialog("Számítás");

        jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        jd.setVisible(true);
        jd.dispose();
    }   
}
```

this is how my code looks like now, I use Jdialog instead of Joptionpane, should i write more characters to make the website accept my edit?

```
import javax.swing.*;



public class Mifasz
{
 private static class Processing extends JDialog{

public Processing(){
    Icon processPic = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Judit\\Desktop\\Mesekocka3D"
            + "\\externals\\pics\\szamitas.gif");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(processPic);
    add(label);
    setTitle("Számítás");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);        
    setSize(400, 70);
    setLocation(330, 300);
    setModal(true);
    setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}       
}

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Processing pc = new Processing();
  }

}
```

Comment: why did you mixing `JDialog` with `JOptionPane` (this is same family of `JComponents`), what do you really want to do, (by ignoring `don't want the user to be able to close it`), one of them is useless, use JDialog or JOptionPane :-)

Comment: I'd like to show a gif for the user for a short time, it's like a loadingscreen, I don't want him to do anything with the app till, so I'm using joptionpane, but I would also like to disable the X button, so I'm using jdialog, becouse I didn't find an option to disable the optionpane's X button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've found a very easy solution:
I just disable the mainframe, while processing.
[How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to show a gif for the user for a short time, it's like a loadingscreen, I don't want him to do anything with the app till, so I'm using joptionpane, but I would also like to disable the X button, so I'm using jdialog, becouse I didn't find an option to disable the optionpane's X button.

1) you can use undecorated `JDialog#setUndecorated(true);`

2) put `gif` as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

3) use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for timing, ooutput from Swing Timer could be a [Swing Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and inside `actionPerformed` put `JDialog#setVisible(fasle);`

EDIT

> i'd like to block it, and it need to be used as many times the user clicks on a JCombobox item

1) create JDialog only once times, you'll reuse that only

2) run Swing Timer#repeat(false) with expecting delay, in `actionPerformed` put `JDialog#setVisible(fasle);`

3) on event from selected `Item` (`JComboBox`) change `Icon` in the `JLabel` `myLabel#setIcon(myAnotherGIF)`

4) inside `invokeLater` wrap `JDialog#setVisible(true);`

5) any another steps aren't required

only in the special cases

6) you have to call

```
myIcon.getImage().flush();
myLabel.setIcon(myIcon);
```

in the case that you have issue with `Icon's` repainting in the `JLabel`

Comment: @Ferenc Dajka see my answer here, my question how many times you want to display this JDialod with Image, in the case that only once time during aplications lifetime, then you don't need to reply somehow...

Comment: JDialog doesn't block the screen like joptionpane, i'd like to block it, and it need to be used as many times the user clicks on a JCombobox item

Comment: @Ferenc Dajka `JDialog#setModal(true);` or there are ModalityTypes, but maybe not important ...

Comment: @Ferenc Dajka see edit in my post about rest from your last comment

Comment: @Ferenc Dajka I think that is designated for Image, ImageIcon, Icon,

Comment: okay it works now, when I've added the label to the dialog first it gave me an exception, maybe i mistyped something, thanks for your help and also for your steadyness ;)

Comment: okay now my original problem was that dispose doesn't work, and it still doesn't work, i really can't get it why

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
jd.setVisible(false);
```

and then

```
jd.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a splash screen, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).