# How to make JFrame to be modal?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, modality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

How to make `JFrame` to be modal?

Please don't suggest to use `JDialog`. The question is about `JFrame`. How to make modal namely it?

Answer (score 4):

to make a JFrame modal u have to write code u'r self, make setEnable(false) 
to the primary window (from where u openning new JFrame ). when user quit 
the Jframe make it setEnable(true)

br

Comment: Are you sure parent window is just disabled when daughter is modal?