# How to lock JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog

Can I lock `JFrame`, when another appears ? Something like when you want open new file, the main window is locked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: ^ Summary: bad practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this not possible with `JFrame`, `JFrame` haven't modality methods, have to use `JDialog`, with follows parametes

1. [`setModal(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) or
2. [`setModalityTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29)
3. don't forget to set `setParent` from `JFrame` to `JDialog`

or to use [`JOptionPane`, block code execution, waiting for users action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use [modal dialogues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html), the ones that block the underlying `JFrame`

Comment: I tried use this modal stuff, but already not working (try exapmles from oracle's link).