# JFrame "blocking" show()

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe, modality

I'm using CHARVA (ncurses-like Swing) and I have a problem.

Because charva is very similar to Swing, I think the solution for Swing is the same to charva.

I'm developing an application that call a `JFrame`-extended class, get
its return code and shows other `JFrame` windows depending on return code.

It's like :

```
public static void main() {
MainFrame mainframe=new MainFrame();
mainframe.show();
switch (mainframe.returncode) {
       case "generalsetting": Frame1 frame1=new Frame1;
       frame1.show();
       break;
       case "usersetting": Frame2 frame2=new Frame2;
       frame2.show();
       break;
```

etc.  But when I do:

```
mainframe.show();
```

The program does not wait until mainframe is closed/hidden, but continue on the "switch", the return code is not initialized and crashes my program.

There is a way to have a "blocking" `show()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java

Answer (score 4):

If you want to perform a blocking call, you can try using a modal `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`: simply use `true` for `modal` parameter in its constructor (see [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29))

Although, I don't know Charva, but `JFrame.show()` is deprecated since Java 1.5 (you shall use `setVisible(true)` instead).

Answer (score 3):

> there is a way to have a "blocking" show()?

Yes. You can make `MainFrame` extend `JDialog` instead of `JFrame` and make it modal:

```
class MainFrame extends JDialog {
    //code...
}
```

---

```
System.out.println("Before");
MainFrame d = new JDialog();
d.setModal(true);
d.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("After");
```

Comment: thanks to you. it doesn't work (simply it continue running), but i'm tired to lose time on charva. i'll find something serious.