# How to set a window non-focusable

Tags: java, swing

I want help in the issue that when I open a child window from the main window then I want main window to be non-focusable when I click on main window i-e the child window should not transfer its focus to the parent window. I am using Java language on Netbeans IDE. Also, I have developed the GUI using Drag n Drop, and I am using swing components.

Comment: Make the child window modal. http://www.coderanch.com/t/339276/GUI/java/form-Modal, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html

Comment: Expansion of the @Robert Harvey comment, this is exactly the reason why modal windows (or dialogues) exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)