# How to have a JFrame be used before using a different one

Tags: java, jframe

I am somewhat new to coding and I need a little help. I am making a program where you start in the main menu. In the main menu there is an options button you can click on that will open a new jframe with the options. I was wondering if there was a way so that you would have to use the new JFrame before using the older (or main) one.

Comment: Do you mean that the new frame should be [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

A modal dialog is one that must be dismissed (closed) before you can interact with program again (an example might be the open/save dialog of Word or your web browser)

But you should also have a read through [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) first...

Alternatively, you could use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which would allow you to switch between views from within the same window

You could also use a [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) which will allow you to have your views presented on the screen and accessible via a "tab", meaning the user can only interact with a single view, but they can navigate to a different view by clicking the tab they want.