# Old JFrame activity while new frame is active

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jframe

How can I deactivate a `JFrame` (up to while new frame is active) under a new frame just like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Abc");` in `Java`?

Comment: Please clarify "deactivate".

Comment: This topic is covered here: [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean that you want to prevent access to the underlying `JFrame` similar to how a `JOptionPane` works. This functionality is possible by using a modal `JDialog` window. Take a look at [`setModalityType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29). More specifically, here is how you might create a modal `JDialog`:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JDialog window = new JDialog(frame); // the frame is the parent
window.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
window.setVisible(true); // must set modality first before making visible
```