# javafx alert dialog on swing frame

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I'm working on an application which is based on swing and javafx 8. In this create a frame in swing and jbutton use and jbutton action code is done in javafx 8 means use scene. in this a alert dialog create.but problem is that if i click anywhere except alert dialog then alert dialog hidden behind swing frame.i want javafx alert dialog keep on swing frame which i create.if i click ok on alert then action is goes to swing frame.
please suggest......

here is my code:

```
    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();


    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            initFX(fxPanel);
        }

        private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Scene scene = createScene();
                fxPanel.setScene(scene);
        }

        private Scene createScene() {

             Group  root  =  new  Group();
             Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root);

             Alert cn=new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
             cn.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

             cn.setTitle(null);
             cn.setHeaderText(null);
             cn.setContentText(ProjectProps.rb.getString("msg.play.confirm"));

             DialogPane dp=cn.getDialogPane();
             dp.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("login.css").toExternalForm());
             dp.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 5px; ");  

             Optional<ButtonType> result=cn.showAndWait();
             if(result.get()==ButtonType.OK){
                 System.out.println("ok button clicked:"+result.get());
                k=0;
             } else{
                 System.out.println("cancel clicked");
                k=1;
             }
            return (scene);
        }

    });
```

Comment: please provide any information....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you really want to do. Do you absolutely need a JavaFX alert in a swing application? JDialog works very well, and Alert and Dialogs works very well too in a JavaFX context.

Have you tried to set your Alert application modal with `cn.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL)` ?

Maybe you can find you answer in this post : [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

This is the suggested code in the post:

```
final JDialog frame = new JDialog(parentFrame, frameTitle, true);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I would create a new JDialog and set as parameter your main frame (parentFrame) and add your JFXPanel to its content.

```
frame.getContentPane.add(fxPanel)
```

You can use `fxPanel.setScene(yourScene)` to add FX content to your JDialog.

Example for the suggestion:

```
public class Main  {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create parent
    JFrame parent = new JFrame("MainFrame");
    parent.setSize(500, 500);

    // center of screen
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    parent.setLocation(dim.width/2-parent.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-parent.getSize().height/2);
    parent.setVisible(true);

    createDialog(parent);

}

private static void createDialog(JFrame parent) {

    // create dialogs JFX content
    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setTop(new Button("HELLO"));
    layout.setBottom(new Button("IT'S ME"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
    JFXPanel dlgContent = new JFXPanel();
    dlgContent.setScene(scene);
    dlgContent.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    dlgContent.setVisible(true);

    // create dialog and set content
    JDialog dlg = new JDialog(parent, "Dialog", true);
    dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    dlg.getContentPane().add(dlgContent);
    dlg.pack();
    dlg.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Hope I could help you.