# Stop code execution until button is pressed

Tags: java

After `choose.setVisible(true)` I would like first
to be able to choose and after pressing the ok button
to continue execution.
The below code shows the `chooser` and `continues`
without waiting.

```
   static class box extends JFrame {
        Checkbox cboxtps = new Checkbox("Grf1", false);
        Checkbox cboxrspt = new Checkbox("Grf2", false);
        JLabel lblQts = new JLabel("Please select graphs");
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Go");

        public box(String str) {
            super(str);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
            add(lblQts);
            add(cboxtps);
            add(cboxrspt);
            add(btn1);
            btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    System.out.println("You clicked the button");
                }
            });
        }
        }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        box choose = new box("Select Graphs");
        choose.setSize(300, 150);
        choose.pack();
        choose.setVisible(true);


        List<File> filepaths = fileselect();
        list = Splitter(filepaths);
}
```

Comment: JFrames are not modal. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java

Comment: Thanks for that theINtoy !  I will implement with JDialog then!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working asynchronously here, you would have to put the code after `choose.setVisible(true)` into the actionPerformed callback like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    System.out.println("You clicked the button");
    List<File> filepaths = fileselect();
    list = Splitter(filepaths);
}
```

In general, when working with a lot of callbacks it is the best to define helper functions to avoid deep nesting.