# JFrame Always on Top With Not Action on Main Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, always-on-top

I have a main `JFrame` which link to another `JFrame` in purpose, 
lets assume main frame is `M` and child frame is `C`, when i click on `M` a `JFrame` `C` opens successfully and here i have added `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` method to `C` `JFrame`. Good every thing is working fine.

But when my `C` JFrame is on top i don't want my `M` `JFrame`  actions work unless `C` JFrame is closed.

This seem to be little awkward and silly question. but please do answer

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556). It's likely one of the frames should be `JDialog`, with the remaining frame as owner. 2) Don't randomly start words with capital (upper case) letters.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle only.

Comment: ya sorry for (upper case), but i only have 2 JFrame, using 2 frames is also not good practice?

Comment: When you are opening frame **C** on button click then, do `M.setEnabled(false)` and when you are closing **C** do the reverse `M.setEnabled(true)`

Comment: *"but i only have 2 JFrame, using 2 frames is also not good practice?"* Multiple means "**two** or more"..

Comment: You are Just saying multiple frames is bad, bad  but why don't you give me some alternate solution then. @David Tanzer helped me. i got the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it looks to me like you want a modal dialog.

Your `C` would basically be a JDialog, and you would set it to `Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL`:

```
JFrame m = new JFrame(...);
JDialog c = new JDialog(m, "", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL );
```

Read more about modal dialogs here:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html
- [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

Comment: Yeh ! this is what i was searching for since weeks you made it easy +1 from me man.