# JAVA - How do I make the user be able to utilize only the frame on top?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When two JFrames are enabled, I want the user to be able to use only one in the top (think of that like an error pop up on your screen, when you can't press anything but the popup itself). I am aware of the class JInternalFrame and I chose not to use it for my program. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a JFrame Modal in Swing java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481405/how-to-make-a-jframe-modal-in-swing-java)

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a modal behaviour, then. I think you can try using JDialog instead of JFrame, something like:

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame, title, true); //parameters: owner, title and modal
dialog.getContentPane().add(somePanel);    
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

You can read more about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Answer (score 2):

Use JDialog, you can set your main frame as the JDialog's parent frame, so that whenever your main frame and JDialog will display, you will be able to click only the JDialog, not your main frame.